# Bash Menu issue / question?

Tags: scripts

There is another thread for this topic but it is closed. I would like to revisit this. I m trying to write a utility script for myself. However i am not a programmer so I wanted to get some feed back. although I do appreciate others attempt to help, I do not want to go off on a tangent and have to read a bunch of stuff. My need is very specific.

```
PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option3" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in


 if [ "$RESP" = "y" ]; then
                action here
        else
                echo "Thank you."
        sleep 2
    exit;  
fi

;;
        "Option 2")
            echo "you chose choice 2"
            ;;
        "Option 3")
            echo "you chose choice 3"
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

How do I get from the exit; or fi back to the menu ?

Thanks very much,

Comment: What's the other thread? This is getting close votes, even though bash scripting is **not off-topic** for Ask Ubuntu. That might be because you've said it's a re-ask of a closed question. Can you tell us what the closed question is, so this can get sorted out? If this is closed as a duplicate of it, then it can still be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

First, you're missing an `"Option 1")` case before your `if`. And `"Option3"` in your options list is missing a space: it should be `"Option 3"`.

Other than that, I can't really understand your question. What's the problem? Once those are fixed, it seems to work for me. Below is a test run. To clarify, `exit` exits the script and returns the user to their shell prompt. If you want to stay in the script, don't use `exit`.

```
ace@ace2:~$ ./test.sh
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
3) Option 3
4) Quit
Please enter your choice: 1
Thank you.
ace@ace2:~$ RESP="y" ./test.sh
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
3) Option3
4) Quit
Please enter your choice: 1
you chose choice 1
Please enter your choice: 2
you chose choice 2
Please enter your choice: 3
you chose choice 3
Please enter your choice: 4
ace@ace2:~$
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in

    "Option 1")
        if [ "$RESP" = "y" ]; then
            echo "you chose choice 1"
        else
            echo "Thank you."
            sleep 2
            exit
        fi
        ;;
    "Option 2")
        echo "you chose choice 2"
        ;;
    "Option 3")
        echo "you chose choice 3"
        ;;
    "Quit")
        break
        ;;
    *) 
        echo invalid option
        ;;
    esac
done
```